# Is there a way to merge a hash field on a document with a new hash on upsert in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, upsert

Suppose I have a MongoDB document with a field `values` which contains a hash `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}`. I then go on to upsert a new version of this document where `values: {c: 4, d: 5}`.

What I am trying to find is a way to have Mongo merge the hashes Mongo-side without me having to pull down the previous version of the document first. I.e. the resulting document after the upsert should have `values: {a: 1, b: 2, c: 4, d: 5}`.

It is currently possible to do this in RethinkDB by providing a custom conflict-resolution lambda function that handles the merging of the old_doc + new_doc. ( https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/ruby/insert/ )

Is it possible to replicate this in Mongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) with $set opeartor. So you will write your query like this

```
 db.<collection_name>.findOneAndUpdate(
 {_id: <id of the doc>}, 
 {$set: {"values.c": 4, "values.d": 5}})
```

Here is an example that I tested out

```
  db.users.findOneAndUpdate(
  {_id: ObjectId("591cd8641c02e094596479ea")}, 
  {$set: {"values.c": 4, "values.d": 5}})
```